# rails <ul> with an array in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, erb

I'm starting out with rails, still working on basics and experimenting

In my view have an array with company names; I'm using erb to just display the items with `<ul>`.

```
<% companies = ["a", "b", "c"] %>
<ul class="list-group">
  <% companies.each do |item| %>
    <li class="list-group-item"><strong><%= item %></strong></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

The page is thus far doing what I want (displaying the company names). I was wondering what the rails way would be to do this, given that the companies array is somewhat lengthy. Is there a better way to handle the information fro the array, without cluttering the view page? Many thanks.

Comment: The Rails way would be to store the company names in the database and load them in a controller...

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. Currently working through Michael Hartl's tutorial, I'll keep an eye as to how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a model called `Company`:

```
#app/models/company.rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

You'll also need the corresponding database values:

```
$ rails g migration CreateCompany

#db/migrate/create_company.rb
class CreateCompany < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      create_table :companies do |t|
         t.string :name
         t.timestamps
      end
   end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

--

This will allow you to store *`Company`* records, with corresponding attributes (`name` being the one highlighted in this example):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :companies #-> url.com/companies

#app/controllers/companies_controller.rb
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @companies = Company.all
   end
end

#app/views/companies/index.html.erb
<ul class="list-group">
  <% @company.each do |company| %>
    <%= company.name %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

---

You could create some test `Company` values by using the [`rails console`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console):

```
$ rails c
$ names = %w(test1 test2 test3)
$ names.each do |name|
$ - Company.create name: name
$ end
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to "paginate" your data.  I.e. you select a size (say 25 items) then you only display that many items on a "page".  At the top (and/or bottom) of the page you have a navigation bar that lets you change pages.

If you had the data in a database, then there are pagination gems that will do this with a couple of lines of code.  A popular one is will_paginate https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate.

If you just want experiment more on the UI side, you can use a jquery pagination plugin:  http://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/  for example.

```
    $('.list-group').twbsPagination({
    totalPages: 35,
    visiblePages: 7,
    onPageClick: function (event, page) {
        $('#page-content').text('Page ' + page);
    }
});
```